# Merge [hp-loadrunner] into [loadrunner]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Merge [hp-loadrunner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hp-loadrunner) (50 questions) into [loadrunner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loadrunner) (936) questions?

Along with the fact that all the questions in both tags are about the same product, there’s also the fact that the product is apparently no longer made by HP but instead by Micro Focus:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LoadRunner